# Renaming files in RStudio that have been sourced other places

Tags: r, refactoring, rstudio

I have a few R files that contain functions imported and used by several other R files. I import these functions with the **source** function. Naturally, the scope of a particular file might change over time, and recently I wanted to rename a file I had already sourced in many other places.

I'm using RStudio, and I have been unable to find a way to do this except for either manually updating each dependent file, or creating some external code to scan through the files.

Is there no way to do consistent renaming in RStudio? Alternatively, am I doing something wrong by using source to add functions?

Comment: You might want to make a package with all your useful functions if there are a lot of them instead of sourcing.  That will help keep the global environment clearer.  Doesn't solve your issue though.

Comment: One simple (hacky) solution that would come to mind would be to add all you `*.R` files to a single directory. Open that directory in a text editor, such as Atom, and do a find replace on that directory. Basically Atom will find/replace all occurrences of a phrase found in that directory.

Comment: Agree with amwill04.  I keep most of my scripts in a single directory (in Dropbox in fact).  A lot of my scripts then create a character string of that directory and I put `source(paste0(gendir, "*.R"))` at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may or may not find this satisfactory.  Create a parent script with the old name that sources the script with the new name.

Extending this, you could just create a general preamble script, called something like "preamble.R", that sources all general utility scripts you have.  Such an approach is common (I believe) with TeX.  Then you only have one place to update file names.

Comment: Ideally I think there should be a way to do something as basic as rename something across documents (e.g. what if a function name changes instead of the file?), but the preamble idea is probably better than what I'm doing currently. I might either go with that, or a package solution as Bazz suggested.

Comment: I'm Bazz also!  The package doesn't solve the renaming issue I don't think.  I guess whatever solution there is is going to be a bit hacky because R is not designed to edit R.  But I don't know of such functionality in RStudio.